# Google Maps fixed position overlay

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm developing a web application which heavily relies on Google Maps. The design I was handed has some vignetting overlayed over the map and I cannot seem to find a solution to implement this while not stealing events from the Google Maps container element.

I've Googled around a bit but have not found a solid solution yet. The suggestions I've found have failed in my tests:

- Using OverlayView will not set it fixed to the container and instead will pan with the map.
- I've tried adding it as a custom control but that appears to be stealing events from the map and make the user unable to pan.

I've even tried injecting my element into a bunch of elements created by Google Maps but no dice.

Is there any way I can achieve this without being too hacky about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that works in modern browsers using the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property. Setting this to `none` on a div that is overlayed over the map results in JavaScript pointer events ignoring my overlay and passing straight through it to the map. What I'm doing is strictly an aesthetic feature so I am not bothered by the lack of IE support.